# I need to display HTML file in report SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a list of html files in a directory

I want to display their contents in SSRS 2008 to print them in PDF.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a one time job?  Is there other information that will be included in the report from datasources or just the html files?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want the contents of the files presented as HTML, including linked images? Should scripts be executed? Or do you want unformatted HTML output? If you are really tied to SSRS, then I would look at importing the contents of the files to a database, perhaps with SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS doesn't have full support of html. Here you can see which html elements SSRS can render:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562.aspx. If you need more - then it's not possible.